# Delphi XE2 - moving projects into SVN

Tags: delphi, svn, delphi-xe2, collabnet

We've finally managed to do the internal housework that should theoretically allow us to start using SVN as our Version Control system.

I've setup the latest version (3.3) of Collabnet Subversion Edge on a server and as far as I can tell it's happily pointed where we want it to be. Getting the Active Directory authentication is different issue)

I've created a new Repository (Timesheets) in the Admin Console with the default "Trunk" "Branch" and Tag" folder.

So I go into Delphi, connect to the repository and store my credentials.  I can see the folders, which are empty.  Exit the dialog and open the Project I want to add to the system.

I right click on the Timesheets.exe in the Project Manager screen, and choose **Add to Version Control**.  It lists the files, and excludes a couple (fair enough).  I browse to the VCS URL and select the "Trunk" folder.  Add a comment, and click Import.

**Boom**

```
Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKCOL request...
```

followed by

```
'G:\Delphi\Timesheets' is not a working copy
```

Which it isn't - ti the first load into the VCS, which I'll then check out to create a Working Copy...

Any pointers?

Comment: Did you [enable WebDAV extensions in your IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis) instance? [`MKCOL`](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc2518.html#rfc.section.5.3) is not plain HTTP, it's WebDAV.

Comment: @kostix Subversion Edge runs on Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was an issue between Delphi XE2 and Subversion Edge 3.3.

Switching to Tortoise SVN allows us to add projects to the repository.